# Can many people edit a post at the same time?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

At times I click the "edit" button, and get this message: "Another edit is awaiting approval for this post. Further edits cannot be submitted until the pending edit is reviewed." *(totally understandable)*

But this time, I got the message *after* I finished editing a post, and clicked the "Save Edits" button. Does this mean many people can edit a post at the same time, and the first one to click the "Save Edits" button will proceed?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, many people *may* be editing a post at the same time.

The only time that an issue would arise if there is a non-zero chance that the edits that you and the other person/people are doing would conflict with one another.  This is actually fairly basic - if you're making a change to the tags and someone else is editing the title, the likelihood of a conflict is low.  However, if you're both editing the body of the post, the likelihood of a conflict is high.

In your case, you ran into another limitation - because you don't have 2,000+ reputation, your edits go into a review queue.  If a post has been edited by someone else, it **must** be reviewed *before* the system allows another person to make changes to it. To answer your question, yes; the first one that edits that post and puts it into review "wins" the race condition.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better put a notification somewhere to let the editors know that someone else is also editing the post, so that the editors won't feel they've invested time on a post for nothing?

Comment: That *does* happen, but if you both submit at the same time, then it might not be apparent.

Comment: I imagine it'll say the exact same thing that you saw @AnnZen.  But I'm not 100% sure when it gets triggered and what the delay is to when your client (browser) sees that.